# How to select values around the cell with NaN value in a 3X3 windows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, nan

I have a following panda dataframe. I need a code to loop over the dataframe and find every NaN value and extract all neighboring pixels around it in a 3X3 windows and save the extracted dataframe into new dataframe which also includes the NaN value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d= {1: [5, 5.11, 5.6, 5.9, 4.8, 6], 3: [4, 5, 15, 25, 40, 10],6: [77, 47, 55, 59, np.nan,  5],
    7: [np.nan, 32, 40, 33, 30, 6],9: [10, 11, 12, 45, 14, 15],15: [3, 5, 9, 12, 11, 12]}            

data_miss=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

See the following picture as a schematic example:

[image]

In this figure, two rectangles green and yellow show the selected values around each NaN value. I need a code that considers NaN values in the borders and does not face error in borders like the selected values in green rectangle that just the values inside the dataframe have been selected. Also, consider that the columns indexes are not in sequential numbers.

Comment: Have you looked into `DataFrame.shift()`?

Comment: I think that my problem is different. We can not solve it with just shifting the rows and cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your dataframe to numpy array:

```
>>> a      # a <- data_miss.values
array([[ 2.,  6.,  4., nan,  6.,  8.],
       [ 8.,  4.,  7.,  9.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 6.,  2.,  1.,  5.,  3.,  9.],
       [ 2.,  8.,  5.,  8.,  9.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  5., nan,  9.,  3.,  8.],
       [ 2.,  9.,  6.,  8.,  4.,  4.]])
```

Define the function:

```
convolve_window = lambda x, y: a[max(x-1, 0):min(x+2, a.shape[0]),
                                 max(y-1, 0):min(y+2, a.shape[1])]
```

Extract around `nan` values:

```
>>> [convolve_window(x, y) for x, y in np.argwhere(np.isnan(a))]
[array([[ 4., nan,  6.],
        [ 7.,  9.,  3.]]),
 array([[ 8.,  5.,  8.],
        [ 5., nan,  9.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  8.]])]
```

If you want to replace `nan` by mean, apply `np.nanmean()`

```
>>> np.nanmean(convolve...)
[5.8, 7.25]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a great solution.